# Make the code in a 'do - while' run once - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

(Ik Its a stupid question) with the "do - while" the code runs multiple times at the same time (i putted a console.log('while') at the beginning, so it print 'while' when the code is executed)  but I want to run it one time at a time. Here's an example:

Code:

```js
let x = 100
let y = 100
do {
  console.log('while')
  /*
  here there's a piece of code that let the user choose what want he to do
  */
  let random = Math.floor(//random number between 1 and 2)
  if (random == 1) {
  y = y - 50
} else {
  x = x - 50
  
} while (y >= 0 && x >= 0 )
```

Obviously the console prints 'while' until the process ends.

I tried to use `for (let i; i < 100; i++)` and in the `for` i putted a `if ( y <= 0 && x <= 0)` but I can't start-over the loop (I dont know how to use `continue`).

Comment: When you say do-while runs multiple times, it must be called multiple times to do the same thing. Can you add full file to see what exactly you want to do?

Comment: `math.floor(...)`  should be `Math.floor(...)`

Comment: @Elitezen yes, I know. I wrote the example here on stackoverflow and not in a IDE. Now im fixing it. Thank you

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Here's a piece of the entire code https://srcshare.io/?id=60b3a70f0b940f83220983b0

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is the brackets - your formatting is incorrect:

```js
let x = 100
let y = 100
do {
  //...
  if (random == 1) {
  y = y - 50
} else {
  x = x - 50
  
} while (y >= 0 && x >= 0 );
```

You don't close off your "do" loop - you just go right into the `while` after the `else`. In order for your code to work properly, you need to insert a bracket after the else:

```js
let x = 100
let y = 100
do {
  //...
  if (random == 1) {
    y = y - 50
  } else {
    x = x - 50
  }
} while (y >= 0 && x >= 0 );
```

Comment: I realized I did a typing error in the question. In my code the brackets are correct.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you are asking. Do-while evaluates sequentially. If there is asynchronous code *within* the loop, then it will NOT run the async code sequentially. So if you launch a process that's asynchronous to get input from the user, the do-while loop will not wait for the processes to complete to keep iterating. For synchronous user input, either look into `async/await` or this wonderful npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync